# Powershell Import-Csv Getting data

Tags: powershell, csv

I've get a csv file, to import and replace some string inside a column.
My piece of code imports data, but the output is with a lot invalid characters.

My csv file is like this:
[image: Excel Screenshot]

But my result is like this:

[image: Powershell Screenshot]

What i´m doing wrong?
Thanks for any help, on this

My code:

```
 Get-ChildItem C:\Scripts\ChangeName\Downloads | ForEach-Object {

 $Current = $_.BaseName.Split('_')[2]
 Import-csv $_.FullName -Delimiter "`t"
 $csv  | ForEach-Object{$_ -replace $Current.Substring(3),$Current}
 $Csv| Export-csv $_.FullName 

 }
```

```
 user_id    firstname   surname path    filename    date    time    deposit_node_id source  resource_type   file_type   superseded_or_current
patriciacosta1  Patrícia    Costa   dowe-legere-0269/0269-legere-dowe/Annotations/2012-06-05_Dowe_text_audio_Khonde_Mzigo.pdf   2012-06-05_Dowe_text_audio_Khonde_Mzigo.pdf 03/06/2017  9:30:37 43293   VuFind  U   document    Current
bagam17 Karsten Legere  dowe-legere-0269/0269-legere-dowe/Plant_names/Annotations/Dowe_plant_names_compilation_Dec_2013_Dowe-Latin.pdf  Dowe_plant_names_compilation_Dec_2013_Dowe-Latin.pdf    04/14/2017  7:48:24 43293   LAT U   Document    Current
bagam17 Karsten Legere  dowe-legere-0269/0269-legere-dowe/Annotations/2012_10_17_text_video_Dowe_Rituals_and_Football_DVD_10.txt    2012_10_17_text_video_Dowe_Rituals_and_Football_DVD_10.txt  09/30/2017  0:19:00 43293   VuFind  U   document    Current
tessascott94    Tessa   Scott   dowe-legere-0269/0269-legere-dowe/Annotations/2012-06-05_Dowe_text_audio_Khonde_Mzigo.pdf   2012-06-05_Dowe_text_audio_Khonde_Mzigo.pdf 11/30/2017  17:34:23    43293   VuFind  U   document    Current
ss123   Sophie  Salffner    dowe-legere-0269/0269-legere-dowe/Annotations/doweweddingsongs_paper.pdf    doweweddingsongs_paper.pdf  01/15/2018  8:43:29 43293   VuFind  U   document    Current
eabdi   Edil    abdi    dowe-legere-0269/0269-legere-dowe/Annotations/2012_06_03_text_video_Dowe_Sherehe_za_Harusi.txt  2012_06_03_text_video_Dowe_Sherehe_za_Harusi.txt    03/01/2018  10:39:07    43293   VuFind  U   document    Current
eabdi   Edil    abdi    dowe-legere-0269/0269-legere-dowe/Annotations/2012_06_03_text_video_Dowe_Sherehe_za_Harusi.txt  2012_06_03_text_video_Dowe_Sherehe_za_Harusi.txt    03/01/2018  10:39:07    43293   VuFind  U   document    Current
```

Comment: it looks like your 2nd image is a BINARY file opened in an editor. also, the 1st image shows something loaded into EXCEL, not a CSV file.. are you ///// **_last, you never load anything into `$csv`_** ...

Comment: Please show us the csv as formatted **text**, not as an image taken from Excel. Next, explain what string in which column should be replaced into what.

Comment: @Lee, the file extension is a csv file. Maybe, you are refer to  file format.

Comment: @Theo, i need to replace all the string cells, in deposit_nsource  column, by the $current variable value. I copy paste part of excel as text.

Comment: Open the file with a text editor like notepad. If you can't read the data in notepad, you don't actually have csv (or tsv) data.

Comment: @joel, you right, opened in notepad and the result is the same.

Comment: Open the file in Excel, and then use the `Save As` option to get actual csv data. **Excel files are not CSV**.

Comment: @Paulo - your image is EXACTLY what one would expect when loading a binary file _as a text file_. [*grin*] so, **_whatever you loaded is NOT a csv file. it's likely one of the proprietary excel formats - pro'ly a `*.xls` file._**

Comment: This is still really unclear. At least now we know what the CSV looks like and (from your code) it uses TAB characters as delimiter. But still We need some examples of what you are trying to achieve. For one thing you need to tell `Get-ChildItem` that you are looking for **files** using the `-File` switch. Next you are probably looking for files of a certain type too, so use parameter `-Filter` aswell. As @Lee_Dailey already pointed out, your variable `$csv` has no value because you are importing the csv but do not store the result in that variable.. And there is no column `deposit_nsource`

Comment: @Theo, the idea is replace all column "deposit_node_id" numbers values  (43293)  for the value of $current variable. Store in the file and save it with the new values. By mistake i refer deposit_nsource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your latest comment, I *think* this is what you are trying to do:

```
$path = 'C:\Scripts\ChangeName\Downloads'

Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Filter '*_*_*.csv' -File | ForEach-Object {
    # get the new value for column 'deposit_node_id' from the file name
    $Current = $_.BaseName.Split('_')[2]
    $csv = Import-Csv -Path $_.FullName -Delimiter "`t"
    foreach ($row in $csv) {
        $row.deposit_node_id = $Current
    }
    # better not overwrite the original csv file, but output a new one
    # $csv| Export-Csv -Path $_.FullName -Delimiter "`t" -NoTypeInformation

    $newFile = Join-Path -Path $path -ChildPath ('{0}_NEW.csv' -f $_.BaseName)
    $csv | Export-Csv -Path $newFile -Delimiter "`t" -NoTypeInformation
}
```